# How to extract files using wildcards in specific sub-directory

Tags: bash, tar

I have a tar file with the following contents:

```sh
$ tar tvf ../mein.tar 
drwxr-xr-x user/user         0 2019-01-14 15:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x user/user         0 2019-01-14 15:30 ./dir2/
-rw-r--r-- user/user         0 2019-01-14 15:30 ./dir2/file21.jpg
-rw-r--r-- user/user         0 2019-01-14 15:29 ./file1.jpg
drwxr-xr-x user/user         0 2019-01-14 15:30 ./dir1/
drwxr-xr-x user/user         0 2019-01-14 15:30 ./dir1/dir11/
-rw-r--r-- user/user         0 2019-01-14 15:30 ./dir1/dir11/file111.jpg
-rw-r--r-- user/user         0 2019-01-14 15:30 ./dir1/dir11/file112.jpg
drwxr-xr-x user/user         0 2019-01-14 15:30 ./dir1/dir21/
-rw-r--r-- user/user         0 2019-01-14 15:30 ./dir1/dir21/file122.jpg
-rw-r--r-- user/user         0 2019-01-14 15:30 ./dir1/dir21/file121.jpg
-rw-r--r-- user/user         0 2019-01-14 15:30 ./dir1/file11.jpg
```

It contains several sub-directories which may or may not contain jpg files. The file names are not always the same, but I know that there is exactly one jpg file in directory 'dir1'. I want to extract this file only, none of the other jpg files, neither in dir2 nor in dir1/dir*.

What I have tried so far is

```sh
$ tar -x -f ../mein.tar --wildcards 'dir1/*.jpg'
tar: dir1/*.jpg: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

or

```sh
$ tar -x -f ../mein.tar --wildcards --wildcards-match-slash 'dir1/*.jpg'
tar: dir1/*.jpg: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

If I use:

```sh
$ tar -x -f ../mein.tar --wildcards  "*.jpg"
```

Then I get all jpg files, this is not what I want.

Does anyone have a clue how to extract the jpg file in dir1 given that I don't know the exact name of that file? What I expect is to get exactly one file in sub-directory dir1, the output should be 'dir1/file11.jpg'.

Comment: have you tried `'./dir1/*.jpg'` instead of `'dir1/*.jpg'` ? note the leading `./` as shown by `tar tf`

Comment: Mine works fine as long as I don't quote it, even when my relative path won't find and expand the filename.

Comment: This does not work either:
`[vboxhain:/tmp/extract]$ tar -x -f ../mein.tar --wildcards  './dir1/*.jpg'`
creates the followinf files
`./dir1/dir11/file111.jpg`
`./dir1/dir11/file112.jpg`
`./dir1/dir21/file122.jpg`
`./dir1/dir21/file121.jpg`
`./dir1/file11.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will offer you the canonical way, used on the times of UNIX:

```
tar xf ../mein.tar `tar tf ../mein.tar|grep -E dir1/[a-zA-Z0-9]+.jpg$`
```

This will work independently of Linux or UNIX and also from the version of tar

Here is my test:

```
[...] ➤ tar tvf ../tar.tar
drwxr-xr-x .......        0 2019-01-15 10:33:31 dir1/
drwxr-xr-x .......        0 2019-01-15 10:21:14 dir1/dir11/
-rw-r--r-- .......        0 2019-01-15 10:21:14 dir1/dir11/file111.jpg
-rw-r--r-- .......        0 2019-01-15 10:21:14 dir1/dir11/file112.jpg
drwxr-xr-x .......        0 2019-01-15 10:21:14 dir1/dir21/
-rw-r--r-- .......        0 2019-01-15 10:21:14 dir1/dir21/file121.jpg
-rw-r--r-- .......        0 2019-01-15 10:21:14 dir1/dir21/file122.jpg
-rw-r--r-- .......        0 2019-01-15 10:21:16 dir1/file11.jpg
drwxr-xr-x .......        0 2019-01-15 10:21:02 dir2/
-rw-r--r-- .......        0 2019-01-15 10:21:14 dir2/file21.jpg
-rw-r--r-- .......        0 2019-01-15 10:21:14 file1.jpg

[....] ➤ tar tf ../tar.tar|grep -E dir1/[a-zA-Z0-9]+.jpg$
dir1/file11.jpg
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work because the second tar does not yield any output. The idea is good, but the tar file has a size of about 26 GB, and with your solution I have to process the file twice which takes quite long.

Comment: This tar yields the required output: `tar tf ../mein.tar | sed -n -e '/[.][/]dir1[/][^/]*jpg/p'`

Comment: @drhuh, please check my updated answer. And IMHO if you want only one file its very hard to avoid double browse of tar file.

Comment: Yes, this should work, but with `tar tf` instead of `tar tvf`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **`--no-anchored`** like this:

```sh
$ tar -xf ../mein.tar --wildcards --no-anchored  "dir1/*.jpg"
```

According to the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html):

> #### File name matching options
>
> ```
> --anchored
>     Patterns match file name start.
>
> --no-anchored
>     Patterns match after any / (default for exclusion).
>
> --wildcards
>     Use wildcards (default for exclusion).
>
> --no-wildcards
>     Verbatim string matching.
> ```

See also [untar only a certain number of files from a large tarball](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42198/128893)

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
tar -xf mein.tar  dir1/*.jpg
```

Comment: Won't that use the command-line wildcard to an existing file? If the file does not already exist locally, then the wildcard will fail?

Comment: This fails:

`[vboxhain:/tmp/extract]$ tar -x -f ../mein.tar --wildcards  dir1/*.jpg
tar: dir1/*.jpg: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

Comment: `[vboxhain:/tmp/extract]$ tar -x -f ../mein.tar  dir1/*.jpg
tar: Pattern matching characters used in file names
tar: Use --wildcards to enable pattern matching, or --no-wildcards to suppress this warning
tar: dir1/*.jpg: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

Comment: What is your tar version?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the following tar: `[vboxhain:/tmp/extract]$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.28`